# Word for ambitious

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word that can be used to describe someone who is ambitious, but with a more positive aspect? Ambitious seems a little negative. I require a word for a person who dreams big, and wants to achieve success.

Thank you

Comment: When did _ambitious_ become negative?

Comment: It's not negative as such, but it's describes a more hard working determined person. I want to find a word which describes a dreamer, or someone who really wants to achieve something in life.

Comment: Perhaps zealous?

Comment: And what did you find in a thesaurus?

Comment: @Jon Snow's papa I think zealous is a great word. If you would post an answer, I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Comment: What was wrong with the suggestions that a thesaurus made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oxford offers many synonyms, like determined, enterprising, pioneering, progressive, motivated, driven, enthusiastic, energetic, commited, purposeful, assertive and eager. Even "ambitious" could work in the right context.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *aspiring*?

I disagree that ambitious has negative connotations though.

Comment: Well I would like to say "He is _." I don't think aspiring would fit, and I still feel ambitious might not be the exact word I'm looking for. I want to say something along the lines of "He dreams big" or "He wants to succeed"

Comment: Not sure you can convey that with one word tbh

Comment: ... Dreaming is certainly a good start, but dreams alone don't get you very far. _What was that superb Dumbledore quote when he warned Harry about watching too much Mirror-of-Erised_?

Answer (score 0):

Words that come to mind are *driven*, *focused* and *committed*.

You may also consider *single-minded* and *goal-oriented* if you don't mind the hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

I think *visionary* could work.

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/visionary) defines as:

> (*adj*) Thinking about or planning the future with imagination or wisdom.

*‘a visionary leader’*

---

> (noun) A person with original ideas about what the future will or
>   could be like.

*'She was a visionary who acheived what many thought to be impossible.'*