# A word for "desire to achieve more"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word which describes "constant desire to achieve more, to gain something, doesn't matter what".

It can't be tied to one goal, like ambition or aspiration. It can be adjective.

Samples:

"I can't rest, my '  ' is driving me forward" OR
"I can't rest, I am too '  ' for that"

EDIT: Okay, I'll try to explain better. Let's say I have 2 choices to make: to eat a salad, OR to eat a chocolate bar. To earn some money OR to watch NETFLIX. So, I choose healthy food and I choose money. I always choose what I think is the best option which leads to maximum gain (subjectively speaking). And I want maximum gain, always. How is that "wanting" called ? Words "ambitiousness" or "driven" don't exactly fit

Comment: So what is wrong with "ambitious"? And you need a sample sentence per the SWR tag.

Comment: Since "desire more" is underspecified and leaving room  for an oblique object, the souhht phrase should do so, too. In my humble opinion, It should not make explicit, that the speaker doesn't know what more could be achieved, but the question suggests otherwise. Which is it, do you know?

Comment: 'Ambition' doesn't need to have a single objective.

Comment: Probably answered at [word for 'ambitious'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/354415/word-for-ambitious).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question:

> I'm looking for a word which describes "constant desire to achieve more, to gain something, doesn't matter what".

I would use [**insatiable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insatiable):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : incapable of being satisfied : QUENCHLESS
>   // had an *insatiable* desire for wealth

To paraphrase the example sentence:

> I can't rest. My desire for more is *insatiable*.

Answer (score 1):

[Driven](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/driven?s=t) (respectively, drive) would fit. From Dictionary:

> Driven 
> adjective being under compulsion, as to succeed or excel: a driven
>   young man who was fiercely competitive.

I can't rest. I am too driven.

Comment: @ marcellothearcane.See times of posting. ;)

Comment: Oops, I can't subtract 

Answer (score 1):

I think driven seems to fit well.

> [Driven](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/driven) - (of a person) relentlessly compelled by the need to
>   accomplish a goal; very hard-working and ambitious.

Especially when talking about personalities driven often refers to the need to accomplish something; anything at all. It differs from ambitious in that it does not neet to be an accomplishment that moves on forward in life or up the ranks at work.

Comment: The comparison to Ger *ich treibe* should be very interesting here. Old English still had the infinitive marker *-en*, if I recall correctly, (cp Ger inf. *treiben* "to drive"); May be *driven* is not a bona-fide passive form as I always thought it were. *Ich bin treiben* basicamly means "I am driving [e.g. the cows up to the alms]"

Answer (score 0):

Motivated - having an incentive or a strong desire to do well or succeed in some pursuit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: More specifically, please cite the source of your definition.

Answer (score -2):

> temptation

The lure of something unknown. A form of self-delusion in case of "my own temptation". *my tempation* expresses at least a personal longing, or vice versa strong pull, but positive connotation is merely implied? Akin to *attempt*; Strongly influenced by christian philosophies of moral warning before the extreme ends of fundamental human tendencies.

Alternatively try

> ambition
>
> allure
>
> attitude (viz *NWA*)
>
> drive
>
> hunger
>
> strive, contention
>
> dissatisfaction
>
> restlessness

Needless to say these are mostly negative, but because your examples are ("can't", "won't"), and all may have a positive connotation as limited as agreement on what constitutes a "gain"

Something more positive for the Zeitgeist may be

> business, busy

It's understood that nobody runs businesses in order to loose after all.

Comment: Not my DV, but "temptation" seems like an antonym to what the OP is asking.